# Least number of terms one would have to take in alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

What would be the least number of terms so that the absolute error of the alternating series $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{10}}$ is less than $0.000287$

Comment: What is your series? $\displaystyle\sum_{i =1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}-\frac{1}{k^{10}}$? $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{10}}$?

Comment: The second option

Answer (score 1):

The error bound for an alternating series states that the error in the truncation to $n$ terms is at most the absolute value of term $n + 1$. Then, we wish to find $k$ such that:

$$\vert a_{k + 1}\vert\leq 0.000287$$

$$\bigg\vert\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(k + 1)^{10}}\bigg\vert\leq 0.000287$$

$$\frac{1}{(k + 1)^{10}}\leq 0.000287$$

$$(k + 1)^{10}\geq \frac{1}{0.000287}$$

$$k \geq (0.000287)^{-\frac{1}{10}}-1\approx 1.2605$$

$$k\geq 2$$

Thus, you can truncate the series to $\boxed{2\text{ terms.}}$